# Post method, but only url parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not sure why I have such a hard time doing this.

I need to post to a url, but without any post-data. It's the url itself that has the data in it.

like so http://something.com/campaigns/campaignfeedback/delete/131/WRBLHRJOESRUFUEHCUSJ

The System.Net.WebClient gives me lots of Upload methods but I have no data to submit, just a url, andf so it gives me a 404.

Any pointers ?

Cheers

Comment: If you want to create a self-answering question so it will be useful to yourself and others in the future, then fine. But at least put some effort into it. You don't really explain what you are trying to do, you don't show your current attempts, and it doesn't appear to have anything to do with asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I believe WebClient's [UploadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx) method uses the POST method by default. If you have no additional POST data to send, you should be able to use an empty string.

```
var url = "http://something.com/campaigns/campaignfeedback/delete/131/WRBLHRJOESRUFUEHCUSJ";

using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.UploadString(url, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with empty string.

```
using ( var wc = new System.Net.WebClient() ) {
    wc.UploadString(apiUrl, "POST", "" );
}
```